# How to manipulate a TiledMap in libGDX?

Tags: serialization, libgdx, tmx, tiled

It looks like libGDX currently doesn't support changing the content of a `TiledMap` in game. I'd like to

- **add / remove tiles** *[SOLVED]*
- **move objects** *[SOLVED]*
- **serialize changes** *[PARTLY SOLVED]*

Are there any third-party solutions addressing (at least some of) these issues? Or how to handle the "delta" in a different object model / file format.

Comment: what do you mean under "in game"? There is Tiled editor which allows to edit tile maps in this format.

Comment: My game character should be able to place and destroy tiles in the map.

Comment: If I remember right map is just an integer array[N][X][Y], where X and Y are dimensions and N is layer. Value of an element is reference to bitmap representing a tile. So, it should be pretty trivial. Of course, it depends on your game logic.

Comment: Well, there is `TiledMapTileLayer.setCell(int x, int y, Cell cell)`, I'll give that a try for issue #1 ..

Comment: hmmm... it seems it has been changed a lot since i worked with it. now they use something called MapObject. you should get layer, then getObjects then you can cast them to RectangleMapObject and you will have coordinates.

Comment: It used to be easire but now they support non-rectangular tiles, so it is the reason.

Comment: Take a look into the renders inside the 'gdx/maps/tiled/renderers'. The render does get single cells to render those. You can do the same and manipulate the cell as you wish by changing the property's and attributes. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.Java and here is a tutorial for animated tiles that does the same, changing tiles to animated ones. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xubOtuq2cEo

Comment: Thank you both for your hints. With your help, I'll handle the first two requirements.

Comment: There is a TmxMapWriter as part of this libgdx-utils library https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils

Comment: This does look promising! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was using libgdx-0.9.8, I got to the very same trouble. When I upgraded to libgdx-0.9.9, the issue got resolved. The TiledMap API got redesigned significantly in version 0.9.9 (actually, it got completely rewritten) and they are not caching tiles anymore so changes in the map are being rendered even when made during the game loop.
Just upgrade the library and rewrite your code to follow the new API.
FMI, see here [New Tile Maps Implementation](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=7197)

BTW, they are going to release version 1.0.0 next week!